# VASIMR thruster at scale

Tags: engines, thrust, plasma, vasimr

I am working on making one, the truth is that the principles are not so difficult, but does anyone have any plans? or reference "with numbers"? because the truth is that it is quite difficult to scale something that you do not know the proportions, but the truth is that I have the materials to make a very basic one to test its principles, can anyone support?

Comment: Had no idea that VASIMR was a registered trademark. I thought it was a NASA acronym.

Comment: It's the brainchild of former astronaut Franklin Chang-Diaz, who started the company http://www.adastrarocket.com/aarc/

Comment: Interesting. I always figured it was developed in NASA.

Comment: ISTR some work was done at NASA at a lab run by Chang-Diaz but they lost interest and he left NASA to keep working on it. Fuzzy on the details though.

Comment: I still think that an electric thermal rocket for main propulsion is kind of weird.

Comment: @ikrase seems a lot less weird than an NTR, and you seem plenty interested in those ;-)

Comment: @Starfish Prime I mean, in NTRs you're using a thermalized heat source to drive a thermal rocket. In gridded ion thrusters and the like, you're using a low-entropy electric work source to do work on a non-thermal rocket. (honestly, the word "rocket" to my intuition kinda implies thermalization). Of course, the extreme temperature makes it less thermalized then, say, chem fuel.